# Exception: Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known native property

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, ngfor

What am I doing wrong?

```
import {bootstrap, Component} from 'angular2/angular2'

@Component({
  selector: 'conf-talks',
  template: `<div *ngFor="talk of talks">
     {{talk.title}} by {{talk.speaker}}
     <p>{{talk.description}}
   </div>`
})
class ConfTalks {
  talks = [ {title: 't1', speaker: 'Brian', description: 'talk 1'},
            {title: 't2', speaker: 'Julie', description: 'talk 2'}];
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [ConfTalks],
  template: '<conf-talks></conf-talks>'
})
class App {}
bootstrap(App, [])
```

The error is

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known native property
("<div [ERROR ->]*ngFor="talk of talks">
```

Answer (score 782, accepted):

I missed `let` in front of `talk`:

```ts
<div *ngFor="let talk of talks">
```

---

Note that [as of beta.17](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta17-2016-04-28) usage of `#...` to declare local variables inside of structural directives like NgFor is deprecated. Use `let` instead.

`<div *ngFor="#talk of talks">` now becomes `<div *ngFor="let talk of talks">`

Original answer:

I missed `#` in front of `talk`:

```ts
<div *ngFor="#talk of talks">
```

It is so easy to forget that `#`.  I wish the Angular exception error message would instead say:
 `you forgot that # again`.

Comment: What exactly is the ampersand for? I fixed my own issues, but I am unsure of what this even does.

Comment: @datatype_void, the hash (`#`) is used to declare a [local template variable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#local-vars)

Comment: I tried using the "let" syntax instead of the # it produced the "Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known native property". Same behavior as you saw in your original question. I changed it back to the # and it seemed to work without any issues. I am using angular2.0.0-rc.1 and I also got the same behavior with angular2.0.0-beta.17

Comment: @Chadley08, create a plunker.  It should work.  Here's a [rc.1 punker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bzuAYivIgrsX1tkw0v01?p=preview) and a [beta.17 plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/v4NoVyE7IwI8RaRHheyM?p=preview) that both work fine.

Comment: Here's an Angular issue about the error message being misleading: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10644

Comment: @PhilGibbins: There already was an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46206911/3345644) reporting what you're mentioning as a possible cause of the error. Be sure to up-vote it, please :)

Comment: Fell in the same hole too, haha. Sneaky `let`. This saved me a couple of minutes of debugging.

Answer (score 95):

Another typo leading to the OP's error could be using `in`:

```
<div *ngFor="let talk in talks">
```

You should use `of` instead:

```
<div *ngFor="let talk of talks">
```

Answer (score 22):

This Statement used in Angular2 Beta version.....

Hereafter use **let** instead of **#**

**let** keyword is used to declare local variable

Answer (score 22):

In angular 7 got this fixed by adding these lines to `.module.ts` file:

`import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
 imports: [CommonModule]`

Comment: Surprised this doesn't have more upvotes. Totally forgot to import CommonModule in one of my modules and ran into this error myself.

Answer (score 13):

In my case, it was a small letter `f`.
I'm sharing this answer just because this is the first result on google

**make sure to write** `*ngFor`

Answer (score 8):

You should use let keyword as to declare local variables 
e.g *ngFor="let talk of talks"

Answer (score 5):

In my case I made the mistake of copying `*ng-for=` from the docs.

https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Correct me if I am wrong. But it seems `*ng-for=` has been changed to `*ngFor=`

Answer (score 5):

For me, to cut a long story short, I had inadvertently downgraded to angular-beta-16.

**The let ... syntax is ONLY valid in 2.0.0-beta.17+**

If you try the let syntax on anything below this version. You will generate this error.

Either upgrade to angular-beta-17 or use the #item in items syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Just to cover one more case when I was getting the same error and the reason was using **in** instead of **of** in iterator

Wrong way  `let file in files`

Correct way `let file of files`

Answer (score 3):

I forgot to annotate my component with "[@Input](https://angular.io/api/core/Input)" (Doh!)

**book-list.component.html** (Offending code):

```
<app-book-item
  *ngFor="let book of book$ | async"
  [book]="book">  <-- Can't bind to 'book' since it isn't a known property of 'app-book-item'
</app-book-item>
```

Corrected version of **book-item.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { Book } from '../model/book';
import { BookService } from '../services/book.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-book-item',
  templateUrl: './book-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./book-item.component.css']
})
export class BookItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  public book: Book;

  constructor(private bookService: BookService)  { }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Also don't try to use pure TypeScript in this... I wanted to more correspond to `for` usage and use `*ngFor="const filter of filters"` and got the ngFor not a known property error. Just replacing const by let is working.

As @alexander-abakumov said for the `of` replaced by `in`.

Comment: my issue was instead of "of" I was using "in"

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
<div *ngFor="let talk of talks"> 
   {{talk.title}} 
   {{talk.speaker}}
   <p>{{talk.description}}</p>
</div>
```

You need to specify variable to iterate over an array of an object

Comment: you have a typo in the code, need to close off the "

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem because I had used 
`*ngFor='for let card of cards'` 
instead of:
`*ngFor='let card of cards'`

had **for** in the beginning like some "for loop"s which was wrong here
it worked, but had the error

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the module containing the component using the *ngFor resulting in this error, was not included in the app.module.ts. Including it there in the imports array resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case,There should be no space between `=` and `"`,

e.g. wrong :

```
*ngFor = "let talk of talks"
```

right :

```
*ngFor="let talk of talks"
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the component was not properly imported in **app.module.ts** file. After importing it everything works fine

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      YourComponent,
      OtherComponents
    ],
    
    imports: [...]

)}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was not declaring the loop variable inside the for loop I had

```
<div *ngFor="pizza of pizzas; index as i">
```

instead of

```
<div *ngFor="let pizza of pizzas; index as i">
```

After declaring it with 'let' it just worked for me.