# How to fix Property binding ng-forOf not used by any directive on an embedded template?

Tags: ecmascript-6, angular, angular2-directives, angular2-template

I'm trying to set-up a simple `ng-for` to loop over a list of project in angular but got stuck with it. I already tried the solution in [Angular2 exception: Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known native property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34012291/802365) (fix missing `#`) but without success.

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ng-forOf' since it isn't a known native property ("<div class="ui link cards">
    <div class="card" [ERROR ->]*ng-for="#project of projects">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="{{project.illustrat"): Projects@1:22
Property binding ng-forOf not used by any directive on an embedded template ("<div class="ui link cards">
    [ERROR ->]<div class="card" *ng-for="#project of projects">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="{"): Projects@1:4
```

#### index.js

```
import * as stylesheet from '../assets/styles/app.scss';

import $ from 'jquery';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
// export for others scripts to use
window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = jQuery;


import 'zone.js/lib/browser/zone-microtask';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'babel-polyfill';

import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

import {App} from './app.component.js'
bootstrap(App, []);
```

#### app.component.js

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Projects} from '../app/projects/projects';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<projects>Loading...</projects>',
    directives: [Projects]
})

export class App {
    constructor(projects:Projects) {
        this.projects = projects;
        console.log(this.projects);
    }
}
```

#### index.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <my-app>
          <ng-content></ng-content>
    </my-app>
<script src="dist/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### project.js

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgFor} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'projects, [projects]'
})
@View({
    //templateUrl: '/app/projects/projects.html',
    directives: [NgFor],
    template: "<div *ng-for='#project of projects'> <p>{{project.description}} </div>",
})
export class Projects {
    constructor() {
        this.projects = [
            {
                "customer": "Matt Giampietro",
                "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet…",
                "name": "project #1"
            },
            {
                "customer": "test",
                "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet…",
                "name": "project #2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

#### Question

- How do I solve this?
- fail both with internal/external template (*i.e.* `templateUrl`)

Comment: As others have suggested, use *ngFor, not *ng-for

Answer (score 4):

`ng-for` isn't correct in recent Angular versions.
Templates were changed to case-sensitive. Now this should be `ngFor`

See also [Can't bind to 'ng-forOf' since it isn't a known native property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34228971/cant-bind-to-ng-forof-since-it-isnt-a-known-native-property)