# Angular exception: Can't bind to 'ngForIn' since it isn't a known native property

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

What am I doing wrong?

```ts
import {bootstrap, Component} from 'angular2/angular2'

@Component({
  selector: 'conf-talks',
  template: `<div *ngFor="let talk in talks">
     {{talk.title}} by {{talk.speaker}}
     <p>{{talk.description}}
   </div>`
})
class ConfTalks {
  talks = [ {title: 't1', speaker: 'Brian', description: 'talk 1'},
            {title: 't2', speaker: 'Julie', description: 'talk 2'}];
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [ConfTalks],
  template: '<conf-talks></conf-talks>'
})
class App {}
bootstrap(App, [])
```

The error is

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForIn' since it isn't a known native property
("<div [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let talk in talks">
```

Comment: try to change this <div *ngFor="let talk in talks"> to this <div *ngFor="let talk of talks">

note: "in" to "of"

Comment: I guess you are from C#/Java background , I did the same mistake of using in instead of Of

Answer (score 964, accepted):

I typed `in` instead of `of` in the ngFor expression.

**Befor 2-beta.17**, it should be:

```html
<div *ngFor="#talk of talks">
```

*As of beta.17, use the `let` syntax instead of `#`. See the UPDATE further down for more info.*

---

Note that the ngFor syntax "desugars" into the following:

```html
<template ngFor #talk [ngForOf]="talks">
  <div>...</div>
</template>
```

If we use `in` instead, it turns into

```html
<template ngFor #talk [ngForIn]="talks">
  <div>...</div>
</template>
```

Since `ngForIn` isn't an attribute directive with an input property of the same name (like `ngIf`), Angular then tries to see if it is a (known native) property of the `template` element, and it isn't, hence the error.

**UPDATE** - as of 2-beta.17, use the `let` syntax instead of `#`.  This updates to the following:

```html
<div *ngFor="let talk of talks">
```

Note that the ngFor syntax "desugars" into the following:

```html
<template ngFor let-talk [ngForOf]="talks">
  <div>...</div>
</template>
```

If we use `in` instead, it turns into

```html
<template ngFor let-talk [ngForIn]="talks">
  <div>...</div>
</template>
```

Comment: And yes, **remember** the `#` before the `talk` variable (as your said: "hope it helps someone else down the road... probably me!")

Comment: @Nobita, yes, that one has tripped me up just as often.  I wrote a Q&A for that one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34012291/angular2-exception-cant-bind-to-ngfor-since-it-isnt-a-known-native-property

Comment: so stinking obvious when you realise... I find it really counter-intuitive, so used to for-in style. I would up vote both your Q&A posts more if I could, thanks

Comment: Thanks Mark. It's not the greatest error message - like WTF is "ngForIn" supposed to mean!? But in retrospect, duh! I wrestled with this for like 20 minutes before I found your Q&A.

Comment: I don't know why the original answer was updated to be only beta 17 + syntax.  I reverted the answer so that it has the pre-beta 17 syntax, with the *new* syntax noted as an update.  Some of us are still on the older betas!  all code updates should be additions to the question or answer, not replacements for the originals.

Comment: I agree that the answer should have both. But I further updated the answer to make it clearer that post beta.17 the syntax is different. (I stopped short of swapping around it so the latest is first). Instead I just put a small note in. At first glance, a newcomer may not realise the latest syntax. Its a minor change but makes a big difference

Comment: please take al look at angular2 forLoop documentation http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/6543/angular-2-forloop#t=201702190649585012149

Comment: looks like the `ngFor let-childSuffix [ngForIn]="children"` thing doesn't work in Angular 6. Is there a way to iterate `in` object keys, not `of` array items? PS nevermind, looks like https://stackoverflow.com/a/51735083/3995261 answers my question

Answer (score 353):

### TL;DR;

Use ***let...of*** instead of ***let...in***  !!

---

If you're new to Angular (>2.x) and possibly migrating from Angular1.x, most likely you're confusing `in` with `of`. As andreas has mentioned in the comments below `for ... of` iterates over `values` **of** an object while `for ... in` iterates over `properties` **in** an object. This is a new feature introduced in ES2015.

Simply replace:

```html
<!-- Iterate over properties (incorrect in our case here) -->
<div *ngFor="let talk in talks">
```

with

```html
<!-- Iterate over values (correct way to use here) -->
<div *ngFor="let talk of talks">
```

So, you must **replace `in` with `of`** inside `ngFor` directive to get the values.

Comment: As an aside - does anyone know the reason behind the use of "of", "in" seems a more natural choice here.

Comment: @mamsoudi @Morvael The difference is that `for..in` iterates the object's keys/properties while `for...of` iterates the object's values. `for(prop in foo) {}` is the same as `for(prop of Object.keys(foo)) {}`. This is a new language feature of ECMA Script 2015 / ES6. So this is only remotely an Angular issue.

Comment: this is what happens when you have been coding in C# for years and then move on to angular

Answer (score 25):

There is an alternative if you want to use `of` and not switch to `in`. You can use `KeyValuePipe` introduced in 6.1. You can easily iterate over an object:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
  {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 15):

use **of** instead of **in**. You can use **KeyValue Pipe** . You can easily iterate over an object:

```
<div *ngFor="let items of allObject | keyvalue">
  {{items.key}}:{{items.value}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

Try to import `import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';` in angular final as `*ngFor` ,`*ngIf` all are present in `CommonModule`

Comment: I'd think this answer would be the more common reason nowadays for getting the error in OP title.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, WebStrom auto-complete inserted lowercased `*ngfor`, even when it looks like you choose the right camel cased one (`*ngFor`).

Answer (score 7):

My problem was, that Visual Studio somehow automatically **lowercased** `*ngFor` to `*ngfor` on copy&paste.

Answer (score 1):

Simply changing "in" to "of" solved my same problem.

```
Chnage <div *ngFor="let talk in talks">

to     <div *ngFor="let talk of talks">
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you create a popup using a new class, so at that time you have to add that class under the

```
declarations: []
```

In `base.module.ts or app.module.ts`

My Example code

##########################MY COMPONENT##################################

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-content',
  templateUrl: './order-details.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styles: []
})

export class NgbdModalContent {
  @Input() orderDetails: any;
  private orderId;
  private customer;
  private orderDate;
  private shipDate;
  private totalAmount;
  private salesTax;
  private shippingCost;
  private transactionStatus;
  private isPaid;
  private isMailSent;
  private paymentDate;

  // private orderDetails;

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {
  }
}
```

###########################BASE MODULE#################################

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
  declarations: [
    NavbarsComponent,
    NgbdModalContent,
  ]
})
export class BaseModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

To add one more gotcha, I naively discovered that if you don't use a `let` statement to assign the index of the loop you also get the same error:

```
<span *ngFor="let button of buttons; i: index; trackBy: trackBy">
...
</span>
```

also throws the same error. The following version fixes it

```
<span *ngFor="let button of buttons; let i = index; trackBy: trackBy">
...
</span>
```

Answer (score -6):

Q:Can't bind to 'pSelectableRow' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'.

A:you need to configure the primeng tabulemodule in ngmodule

Answer (score -20):

my solution was - just remove '*' character from the expression ^__^

```
<div ngFor="let talk in talks">
```