# How to generate checkboxes using *ngFor and a list of maps

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have the following map

### .dart

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> symptoms = [
  {'name': 'Dizziness', 'checked': false},
  {'name': 'Fainting', 'checked': false}
];
```

My **incorrect** attempt in html is shown below

### .html

```
<div class = "form-group">
        <div class = "form-control"
             ngControl = "symptoms">
          <label for="symptom" >Symptoms</label>
            <input
              type = "checkbox"
              *ngFor = "#symptom in symptoms"
              [checked]="symptom['checked']"/>

        </div>
  </div>
```

My issues are as follows:

> 1. The label for each checkbox should be "symptom['name'] - how do I integrate this in the *ngFor?
> 2. How can I determine that a specific checkbox was selected?

### EDIT 1

I am now seeing the checkbox and the label using the following:

```
  <div layout = "row"
       layout-align = "center"
       class = "form-group"
       *ngFor = "#s of symptoms">
    <label>{{s['name']}} </label>
    <input
        type = "checkbox"
        [checked] = "s['checked']"
        class = "form-control"/>
  </div>
```

However, the label seems to be on one row and the checkbox on another. I am using bootstrap.min.css and wonder if this is the main cause. The checkboxes are larger than expected too as shown below:

[image]

Cheers, and thanks
Teddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ngFor` syntax is incorrect. The expression should be "#binding **of** list", not **in**. See [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561168/angular2-exception-cant-bind-to-ngforin-since-it-isnt-a-known-native-proper) for a more elaborate explanation.

Also if you want to repeat the label and the checkbox, you need to move the template higher up the DOM tree. For this, use the expanded `ngFor` syntax.

Finally, use `ngModel` instead of binding to `checked` - the existence of the attribute must be [checked="checked"](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp) which does not make it ideal for binding to a `Boolean`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [NgFor],
  template: `{{title}} <br />
  <form>
  <div class = "form-group">
        <template ngFor #symptom [ngForOf]="symptoms">
        <div class = "form-control">
          <label for="symptom" >{{symptom.name}}</label>
            <input
              type = "checkbox"
              ngControl="symptom"
              [(ngModel)]="symptom['checked']" />
        </div>
        </template>
  </div>
  </form>
  `
})
```

[Demo Plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XfvtSZeS8wVMABDEcBea?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much. The 'in' used is due to mixing expressions in Dart with Angular - my mistake. Your Plnker demo runs fine, but I am wondering about the lable name - {{symptom.name}} - should it not be {{symptom['name']}} instead? It is the only one that works with Dart. How do I determine which checkbox was checked?

Comment: I'm not sure if Dart changes things, as I don't know Dart. But either should work: symptom.name or symptom['name'] - both are equivalent.  To determine which checkbox was checked, you can add a click handler: (click)="onClick(symptom)". See the demo.