# Property binding ngForIn not used by any directive on an embedded template - Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

Trying to run a `*ngFor` within the html like this.
But, this error shows up.

```
Property binding ngForIn not used by any directive on an embedded template
```

This is the html code:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="#media in medias">
```

I've had this happen in my previous project as well, still figuring it out. Any clues?

Still new to Ionic2 & Angular2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 exception: Can't bind to 'ngForIn' since it isn't a known native property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561168/angular2-exception-cant-bind-to-ngforin-since-it-isnt-a-known-native-proper)

Comment: Basically you have to do `#variable of array`, not `#variable in array` (`of` vs `in`)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Your are mistaken with angular1 syntaxes:

Instead of `*ngFor="#media in medias"`,

you have to write `*ngFor="#media of medias"`

**UPDATE** - as of beta.17, use the `let` syntax instead of `#`.  This updates to the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let media of medias">
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html