# Angular 2 *ngFor syntax

Tags: angular, angular2-template

My main issue was trying to loop for a certain number of times let's say n, but the `ngFor` only accepts arrays, like: "`#item of [1, 2, ..., n]`", so what is the proper way to loop using only the item count (without creating a useless array that has only numbers one to n)?

so I started reading more into the syntax and then i noticed that there are:

- `*ngFor="#item of items;`
- `*ngFor="#item in items;`

so what is the difference between "in" and "of" and what are there use cases? and does it have anything to do with my original case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34561169/4933038

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no

```
*ngFor="#item in items;
```

you have to use `of`.
Early versions required `in` but they changed it to conform to https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

It should be

```
*ngFor="let item of items; ..."
```

Currently `ngFor` only iterates over arrays.

Answer (score 2):

`of` does refers to each element of `items` collection which is `#item`. `#item` is local variable created for each element rendered by `*ngFor`.

`in` was there in Angular 1 version, it isn't supported in Angular2 `ngFor` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

for resembling syntax with ES6 angular did this change.
In ES6,

```
for (var v of arr){
   console.log(v); // it will return value (not key like in for...in)
}
```

Similarly in Angular 2.0 they followed same syntax.

```
*ngFor="#item of items;
```

will return values.

`in` was in angular 1, which was resembled with `for(var i in arr)`. but no more supported in angular 2.0