# Can ngForIn be used in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I am trying to iterate over the properties of an object using `*ngFor` but using `in`. When I try to do this

```
@Controller({
  selector: 'sample-controller',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let i in obj">
        <b>{{i}}</b>: {{obj[i]}}
      </li>
    </ul>`
})
class SampleController {
  obj = {a: 1, b: 2}
}
```

I get the error message:

> Can't bind to 'ngForIn' since it isn't a known property of 'li'.

I have included `FormsModule` and `BrowserModule` in the `imports` section of the `@NgModule` for this component.

Is it possible to use `ngForIn` on `li` and if not is there an idiomatic alternative?

Comment: Is it [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34561169/2908576)?

Comment: @HaveSpacesuit No, I want to iterate over object properties explicitly, not iterate over an iterable like an array.

Comment: https://medium.com/@jsayol/having-fun-with-angular-extending-ngfor-to-support-for-in-f30c724967ed

Comment: @AJT_82 Ah ok, I was hoping I could get this done without writing a directive, but I'll just do that then. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, it is not included in the maaaagical Angular box unfortunately, you need to tinker a bit. Good luck and have fun with that :) One option is to use a custom pipe of course, just to mention that (more common) option.

Comment: you want `let i of obj` NOT `let i in obj`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As AJT_82 mentioned in comment you can create special directive for such purposes. It will be based on `NgForOf<T>` directive:

```
interface NgForInChanges extends SimpleChanges {
  ngForIn?: SimpleChange;
  ngForOf?: SimpleChange;
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngFor][ngForIn]'
})
export class NgForIn<T> extends NgForOf<T> implements OnChanges {

  @Input() ngForIn: any;

  ngOnChanges(changes: NgForInChanges): void {
    if (changes.ngForIn) {
      this.ngForOf = Object.keys(this.ngForIn) as Array<any>;

      const change = changes.ngForIn;
      const currentValue = Object.keys(change.currentValue);
      const previousValue = change.previousValue ? 
                            Object.keys(change.previousValue) : undefined;
      changes.ngForOf =  new SimpleChange(previousValue, currentValue, change.firstChange);

      super.ngOnChanges(changes);
    }
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/6tDTIfl14chTOJfEzKbr?p=preview)**

Comment: Those who stumble across this and have upgraded angular `ngForOf` no longer implements `OnChanges`. The trick is to just set the value of your `forOf` into the `super.ngForOf`. Full directive here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62086663/2103767

Answer (score 3):

The easiest approach would be to turn your object into an array using `Object.values()` and `Object.keys()`. Check out [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/XoKS3LUZ7UWFg6wN3bu0?p=preview) for an example.

If you want access to the keys as well as the value you can include an index in your `*ngFor`.

**Template:**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of array; let index = index;">
    <b>{{keys[index]}}</b> value: {{item}}, index: {{index}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Component TypeScript:**

```
export class App {
  obj = {a: 1, b: 2}
  array = [];
  keys = [];
  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.array = Object.values(this.obj);
  this.keys = Object.keys(this.obj);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Things have changed a bit (at Angular 9) so the answer by yurzi wont work but on the similar lines setting your 'forOf' value into 'super.ngForOf' will do the trick

```
import {   ContentChildren,   Directive,   Input,   IterableDiffers,   NgIterable,   OnChanges,   SimpleChanges,   TemplateRef,   ViewChildren,   ViewContainerRef } from "@angular/core";

import { NgForOf } from "@angular/common";

export interface Selectable<T> {   selected: boolean;   isActive: boolean; }

@Directive({   
 selector: "[optionsFor][[optionsForOf]]" }) 
 export class OptionsForDirective<T extends Selectable<any>,U extends NgIterable<T> = NgIterable<T>> 
     extends NgForOf<T, U> implements OnChanges {   

   _editMode = false;   
   _forOf: Array<Selectable<any>>;

  @Input()   
  set iefOptionsForOf(value: any) {
    this._forOf = value;
    console.log("set of: ", value);   
  }

  @Input()   
  set iefOptionsForEditMode(value: boolean) {
    this._editMode = value;
    console.log("set edit mode: ", value);   
  }

  constructor(
    public _viewContainer2: ViewContainerRef,
    public _templateRef2: TemplateRef<any>,
    public _differs2: IterableDiffers   ) {
    super(_viewContainer2, _templateRef2, _differs2);   
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.optionsForOf) {
      const origNgForOf: Array<Selectable<any>> = this._forOf;
      let filtered = origNgForOf;
      if (origNgForOf) {
        filtered = origNgForOf.filter(s => {
          return this._editMode || s.isActive !== false;
        });
      }
      console.log("filtered", filtered);

      super.ngForOf = filtered as any;
    }   
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys` and `Object.values` can be assigned to public properties on the component and then they are available as functions in a template. eg

```
//somewhere in the component
public objectKeys = Object.keys;
public objectValues = Object.values;

//somewhere in template
...*ngFor="let key of objectKeys(someObject)"...
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use the keyValue pipe.

```html
<span *ngFor="let keyValue of myObject | keyValue">
    {{ keyValue.key }} - {{ keyValue.value }}
</span>
```