# Observable with Angular 4 , NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as arrays

Tags: json, angular, typescript, observable, angular-components

Yes,  I see that other people get this error , I just don't quite get how to fix it in my code

```
private _url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH,LTC,EOS,DASH&tsyms=USD'
```

If I didn't have the `return` it does not crash with the error , but I do want to return the data.

I have a component that calls up this method  ( in this service ts file )

**Subscriber:**

```
getAllCoins() {

    var blah = [];

    return this.getCoins().subscribe(
        data => {
            blah = data;               
            //console.log('subscriber coins', blah)
        }
    )

}
```

Calls this code

```
getCoins() {
    return this.http.get(this._url)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        //.do(data => console.log(data))
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))  // do operator to peek 
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Now,  I see that the data from the url looks like this

```
{
"BTC": {
  "USD": 3349.1
},
"ETH": {
  "USD": 296.3
},
"LTC": {
  "USD": 47.56
},
"EOS": {
  "USD": 1.83
},
"DASH": {
  "USD": 195.83
}
}
```

How can I prevent from getting this error  `errors.ts:42 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

**UPDATE for comment question**

```
@Component({
template: `
<div>test</div>
<div *ngFor="let coin of coinsList">
 abc
 </div>
`
})
```

Comment: Does it return one object always or is there a possibility of returning an array ?

Comment: You don't need an array, can implement you own iterable on an object very easily https://stackoverflow.com/a/45321622/2545680

Comment: Can you help show me,   I don't quite get this

Comment: @JohnBaxter, how do you use `blah` in the template and how do you expect to see the rendered `html`? Show in your question

Comment: @Maximus   -  trying to use it like in my updated question showing that code for the template    thx

Comment: @JohnBaxter, there's no `coinsList` in your code. Can you be more specific? What data will you be using from `coinsList` in your html, the `abc` doesn't tell much

Comment: `this.coinsList = this.coinService.getAllCoins()`      abc is placeholder , if it truly looped over the data returned it would repeat abc for each ..

Comment: I can't seem to get past this return of the type of data though  -  observables

Comment: The data returned from the URL is an object, not an array.  The format of your data returned from service should be contained in square brackets e.g. `[{...},{...}]`

Comment: Where have you seen an example/tutorial that uses ngFor over an observable like this?

Comment: @Brad  -  how do I get the data into brackets?

Comment: @echonax    `*ngFor='let product of products`       from   here   `https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-GettingStarted/blob/master/APM%20-%20Final/app/products/product-list.component.html`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As others have said, `*ngFor` only works on iterables.

There are a couple of methods that can be done to overcome this problem. Ones that come to my mind right now are:

1) You can push your list of objects to an Array.

```
this._ConfigurationService.getCoins()
            .subscribe(
            (data)=> {
                for(let key in data){
                  this.coinsList.push(data[key]);
                }
            },
            (error) => console.log("error : " + error)
        );
```

template:

```
<div *ngFor="let coin of coinsList">
    <span>{{coin | json}}</span>
</div>
```

Full plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/zrzVF8qKl8EvKKp2Qt45?p=preview

2) You can convert the response from object to an iterable using a pipe as shown in here: [How to iterate [object object] using *ngFor in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396435/how-to-iterate-object-object-using-ngfor-in-angular-2)

3) You can implement the iterable function to your object as shown here: [Angular NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45321119/angular-ngfor-only-supports-binding-to-iterables-such-as-arrays/45321622#45321622).

4) You can create special directive as shown here: [Can ngForIn be used in angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45151334/can-ngforin-be-used-in-angular-4/45151862#45151862)

My suggestion would be to use the first one for simplicity.

Comment: For some reason I am getting an error     ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined      I'm doing the same thing in which I subscribe to the service

Comment: Oh, the only different is that if I set    `coinsList:[]`  , then the  `this.coinsList.push(data[key])   show error of  `Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'`    ,  so I changed  to `coinsList:any;     no visual errors -  but the push error  which I suppose makes sense with an array  ..  ugh    how come your plunker works

Comment: @JohnBaxter you are probably not initializing `coinsList`. I've initialized it in the fields `coinsList = [];` you are just declaring its type with `coinsList:[];`. That is, `:` and `=`  is not the same operation. Spot the differences between the two pictures :-)

Comment: Yes,  -  cool  it works   -  I am liking typescript, just not thinking about javascript     ha   thx again

Comment: @JohnBaxter no problem :-)

Comment: -    I didn't get a chance to get back to working out how to format my data ,  I hate the API returned data   I posted a question here     thx if you have time    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45727951/angular-4-display-data-that-is-in-this

Answer (score 1):

As the erorr says you are trying to do a **`ngFor`** over Object, it works over any iterables.

Probably you can iterate over them and create an array, and then use it for the ngFor.

Comment: it works over any iterables, not just an array https://stackoverflow.com/a/45321622/2545680

Comment: Wait,  how can I do this?    Seem like i'm doing things fine with subscriber and the method it calls , or is there a better way of writing that code ?

Comment: I see that some people use Observable and do not even use  subscribe -   can/should I change my code,  how ?      `getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
            .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }`