# Angular 4 display data that is in this

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I do not like the data that is coming back from an API to my angular 4 application.

Here is an example of the JSON ,   I don't care anything about the USD, but this is the type of data that I'm dealing with

End goal is to display on the page

```
Coin   Price

BTC    $4,281.28
ETH    $294.62 
etc..
```

JSON

```
{
    "BTC": {
    "USD": 4281.28
    },
    "ETH": {
    "USD": 294.62
    },
    "LTC": {
    "USD": 43.4
    },
    "EOS": {
    "USD": 1.7
    },
    "DASH": {
    "USD": 197.69
    }
}
```

Service file

```
getAllCoins(): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.get(this._url)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .do(data => console.log('coins ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError)

}
```

Component file that subscribes to coinService

```
this.coinService.getAllCoins()
        .subscribe(
        (data) => {
            for (let key in data) {
                this.coinsList.push(data[key]);
                console.log('key', key)
            }
        },
        (error) => console.log("error : " + error)

        );
```

Finally then the template html

```
 <div *ngFor="let coin of coinsList">
  <span>{{coin | json}}</span>
</div>
```

I can see that `key`  will display  BTC etc.. in console.log 
and then on the page I see

```
 { "USD": 4234.31 }
```

But I don't want to see brackets and all that ,  but  instead   coin (BTC)  and Price    -

Should I push different data into my array ?   `coinsList = [];`

Comment: I don't think you need to use the json pipe(`coin | json`)

Comment: then I get   [object Object]

Comment: try  by pushing like blow in your `for in` loop `this.coinsList.push({coinName:key,price:data[key].USD})`
and then in view 
`<div *ngFor="let coin of coinsList">
  <span>{{coin.coinName}}   {{coin.price}}</span>
</div>`

Comment: You could do as Rahul mentions, or follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35536052/1471485

Comment: I have modified your `coinList` array to have array like object with coinName and its respective price

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please update your code like below :

```
this.coinService.getAllCoins()
        .subscribe(
        (data) => {
            for (let key in data) {
               this.coinsList.push({coinName:key,price:data[key].USD}); //change is here
                console.log('key', key)
            }
        },
        (error) => console.log("error : " + error)

        );
```

and in View

```
<div *ngFor="let coin of coinsList"> <span>{{coin.coinName}} {{coin.price}}</span> </div>
```

This should yield your desire result.

Comment: I would probably also add a filter for currency    e.g.   `<span>{{coin.coinName}} {{coin.price | currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2'}}</span>`     regardless -  this is a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the json pipe

```
<div *ngFor="let coin of coinsList">
  <span>{{coin}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: [object Object]

Comment: you need to maintain a valid field name for this

Comment: and access coin.BTC

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this.
You can also do something like:

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let coin of coinsList; let i = index;">
      <span>{{keyList[i]}}:  $ {{coin}}</span>
</div>
```

ts:

```
for(let key in data){
   this.coinsList.push(data[key]["USD"]);
   this.keyList.push(key);
}
```

Note: [Rahul Naik's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1608841/rahul-naik) Array of object's [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45728213/5706293) is cleaner in my opinion.

Note2: You can also create a custom pipe.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/zrzVF8qKl8EvKKp2Qt45?p=preview