# How to loop over object properties with ngFor in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

this is post is about an interesting problem I found at work.

If you don’t know it yet. I’m talking about Angular 2+

**The problem**

So you want to display the markup for a list, the values for this list come from the back end and for some reason instead of a good old array of objects you receive something like this.

```
    { 
  "car" : 
    { 
       "color" : "red",
       "model" : "2013"
    },
   "motorcycle": 
    { 
       "color" : "red",
       "model" : "2016"
    },
   "bicycle": 
    { 
       "color" : "red",
       "model" : "2011"
    }
}
```

Then you try to use *ngFor but a wild error message appears:

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

You might fix it in the back end so you get an array of objects, but ain’t no body got time for that. Don’t you worry child, I’ve got us.

Answer (score 206):

In Angular 6.1 the KeyValuePipe was introduced which allows you to iterate object properties:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
  {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```

Docs: https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

Comment: fine, but in my case, i am getting second item is rendering as first in UI. any suggestion ?

Comment: yes, I have experienced this issue also - have raised a question here to see if anyone has the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52793944/angular-keyvalue-pipe-sort-properties-iterate-in-order

Comment: See @ConnorsFan answer at the link in above comment

Answer (score 29):

I don't know if this is safe, but for these simple cases i don't like the pipe solution, so i usually use:

```
<div *ngFor="let k of objectKeys(yourObject)">
    {{yourObject[k].color}}
</div>
```

and in the controller:

```
objectKeys(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj);
}
```

This is a quite frequent case, i don't understand why there isn't a standard implementation for this like in Angular.js 1.x

Comment: This is the best!

Comment: do not use functions in the template (except events). It will slow down your app, create a pipe instead. Angular change detection will call this function a lot because, if it wats to know if the value was changed it has to call it so, it's called by change detection loop which results in a slow app.

Answer (score 14):

A better solution would be to use a pipe such as this one:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Convert Object to array of keys.
 */
@Pipe({
  name: 'appProperties'
})
export class PropertiesPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: {}): string[] {

    if (!value) {
      return [];
    }

    return Object.keys(value);
  }
}
```

Then in your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let property of response | appProperties">
    <div *ngFor="let item of response[property]">
         {{item.something}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are right, if the project needs it in more than one instance, your solution seems more scalable.

Answer (score 12):

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of donation_list | keyvalue">
        <div class="donation-box">
             <Label class="donation-label">Date : {{item.value.PaymentDate}}</Label>
             <Label class="donation-label">Time : {{item.value.PaymentTime}}</Label>

        </div>
   </div>
```

If you have more properties inside the object, you can use like this.

Answer (score 2):

Use Object.values to get a regular array from your object. Object.keys seems like a lot of unnecessary work.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways:

1. If your object items don't have key

   ```
   { name: 'John', age: 18,... }

   <div *ngFor="let item of myObj | keyvalue">
       Key: <strong>{{item.key}}</strong> and Value: <span>{{item.value}}</span>
   </div>
   ```
2. If your object items have key

   **Pipe**

   ```
   import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

   type Args = "keyvalue" | "value" | "key";

   @Pipe({
       name: "pipeMapToIterable",
       pure: false
   })
   export class MapToIterablePipe implements PipeTransform {
       transform(obj: {}, arg: Args = "keyvalue") {
           return arg === "keyvalue" ?
               Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({ key: key, value: obj[key] })) :
               arg === "key" ?
                   Object.keys(obj) :
                   arg === "value" ?
                       Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]) :
                       null;
       }
   }
   ```

   **HTML**

   ```
   { 
       John: { name: 'John', age: 18 },
       Bob: { name: 'Bob', age: 25},
       Marry: { name: 'Marry', age: 22}
   }

   <!-- default -->
   <div *ngFor="let item of myObj | pipeMapToIterable">
       Key: <strong>{{item.key}}</strong> and Value: <span>{{item.value}</span>
   </div>


   <!-- keyvalue -->
   <div *ngFor="let item of myObj | pipeMapToIterable : 'keyvalue'">
       Key: <strong>{{item.key}}</strong> and Value: <span>{{item.value}</span>
   </div>


   <!-- value -->
   <div *ngFor="let item of myObj | pipeMapToIterable : 'value'">
       Key: <strong>{{item.key}}</strong> and Value: <span>{{item.value}</span>
   </div>


   <!-- key -->
   <div *ngFor="let item of myObj | pipeMapToIterable : 'key'">
       Key: <strong>{{item.key}}</strong> and Value: <span>{{item.value}</span>
   </div>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**The solution**

In a perfect world, you would get an array of objects, since the world is not always, perfect. What you want to do, is to store all those objects within an array. Here is an over-simplified solution in plain old JavaScript.

**Step 1.** Get all the object keys. using Object.keys. This method returns an array of a given object’s own enumerable properties.

**Step 2.** Create an empty array. This is an where all the properties are going to live, since your new ngFor loop is going to point to this array, we gotta catch them all.

**Step 3.** Iterate throw all keys, and push each one into the array you created.

Here’s how that looks like in code.

```
// Evil response in a variable. Here are all my vehicles.
let evilResponse = { 
  "car" : 
    { 
       "color" : "red",
       "model" : "2013"
    },
   "motorcycle": 
    { 
       "color" : "red",
       "model" : "2016"
    },
   "bicycle": 
    { 
       "color" : "red",
       "model" : "2011"
    }
}
// Step 1. Get all the object keys.
let evilResponseProps = Object.keys(evilResponse);
// Step 2. Create an empty array.
let goodResponse = [];
// Step 3. Iterate throw all keys.
for (prop of evilResponseProps) { 
    goodResponse.push(evilResponseProps[prop]);
}
```

Then you can assign the goodResponse to the class property you were trying to iterare trough in the first place.

That’s all folks.

Comment: This kind of doesn't show how to iterate properties in ngFor, which was aked. This is how you do it in javascript.

Comment: evilResponseProps[prop] should be evilResponse[prop].

Comment: You can also do this like this: Object.keys(evilResponse).forEach(function (key) { goodResponse.push(evilResponse[key]; }

Comment: This is not the answer to the question that was asked, at all.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
  {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```

For more info visit: https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

Answer (score -1):

declare your array as any and then assign your object

```
data=[] as any;
myObj={};

data=myObj;
```

now loop through data array

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of data">
<td>{{item.property}}</td>
</tr>
```