# how to reference coinlist data from this json response in ionic

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, nested

Here is the API link https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist

I want to get currency Name and Symbol, how do i refer in ionic angular ...

here is my code in ionic coin.ts file

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

    import { Http } from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-convert',
      templateUrl: 'convert.html',
    })
    export class ConvertPage {

        public coins: any;

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {

        this.http.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
            this.coins = data.Data;
        });
      }

    objectKeys(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj);
    }

    }
```

here is the code from coin.html

```
    <select>
    <option *ngFor="let coin of objectKeys(coins)" value="0">{{coins[coin].Name}} (BTC)</option>
    </select>
```

now i am getting this error 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: what exactly is the problem? any errors?

Comment: I get this error

ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: your url is giving a number of nested objects not an array. `this.coins` is _not_ an array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop over object properties with ngFor in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45819123/how-to-loop-over-object-properties-with-ngfor-in-angular)

Comment: Thank you for your response, so how to refer nested objects?

Comment: check the dupe link.. you get an object similar to that

Comment: i have tried solution but its not working