# Iterate through Object array - *ngFor - Angular 6

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, ecmascript-6

Could some one tell me how to iterate below data structure. ii'm trying to load in normal bootstrap table. but failed. so far i tried to `for..loop` inside an `for of` loop. but it returns **undefined** on '`tableData`'

i know its silly and duplicate question. but i don't find solution.

```
{
"parent":{  
      "tableHeading":{  
         "Header1":"ASD",
         "Header2":"QQQ",
         "Header3":"YYY",
         "Header4":"OOO",

      },
      "tableData":[  
         {  
            "Sample_1":"2019-08-19T00:00:00",
            "Sample_2":"Johney",
            "Sample_3":"30",
            "Sample_4":"PA,

         },
         {  
            "Sample_1":"2019-08-19T00:00:00",
            "Sample_2":"Allen P",
            "Sample_3":"29",
            "Sample_4":"SA",

         },
         {  
            "Sample_1":"2019-08-19T00:00:00",
            "Sample_2":"Chris",
            "Sample_3":"28",
            "Sample_4":"MM",

         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379274/how-to-iterate-over-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object) although I just noticed `*ngFor`, so pardon if this doesn't help. Can you clarify your intent with an example HTML snippet that you're adding the directive to? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop over object properties with ngFor in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45819123/how-to-loop-over-object-properties-with-ngfor-in-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let head of data.parent.tableHeading |keyvalue">
            {{head.value}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of data.parent.tableData">
        <td *ngFor="let element of item | keyvalue">
            {{element.value}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-weacwe)

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a perfectly working solution with a Stackblitz demo...

Comment: @AdritaSharma your solution correct. but i've used some way to render data. thanks for your time