# ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables Angular 9

Tags: json, angular, observable, angular9

hello every one i have this error ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables

i tried .json but it s not working in angular 9

**My component .html**

```
  <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Ville</label>
                <select class="form-control" #hh
                    (change)="getidregion(hh.value)">
                    <option></option>
                    <option *ngFor="let ville of dropDownList"
                        [value]="ville.id">
                        {{ville.nomVille}}
                    </option>

                </select>

            </div>
```

**My Component.TS :**

```
dropDownList: [];

  responsable = {

    id: 0,
    nomResponsable: '',
    prenomResponsable: '',
    emailResponsable: '',
    mdpResponsable: '',
    img: '',
    rib: '',
    dtn: '',
    region: 0,
    ville: 0,
  };

    methodAPIToGetVilles() {
        this.res.getville()
          .subscribe((s: any) => {
            this.dropDownList = s;
    
          });
      }
    
      //methode to get the value off the idville in the option
      getidville(id: any): void {
        this.responsable.ville = id;
    
      }
    
      curUser: any = this.responsable[0];
```

**My API  Data  :**

```
"@context": "/api/contexts/Ville",
    "@id": "/api/villes",
    "@type": "hydra:Collection",
    "hydra:member": [
        {
            "@id": "/api/villes/6",
            "@type": "Ville",
            "nomVille": "Davidboeuf"
        },
        {
            "@id": "/api/villes/7",
            "@type": "Ville",
            "nomVille": "Benoitboeuf"
        }];
```

Comment: Your API doesn’t return an array probably?

Comment: yes it returns an object i don t know how to convert it

Comment: Can you post it? There is a way to loop through an object as well using the keyvalue pipe.

Comment: use console.log(this.dropDownList) and check what it showing

Comment: this is My console log  : `{@context: "/api/contexts/Ville", @id: "/api/villes", @type: "hydra:Collection", hydra:member: Array(30), hydra:totalItems: 403, …}
@context: "/api/contexts/Ville"
@id: "/api/villes"
@type: "hydra:Collection"
hydra:member: Array(30) 0: {@id: "/api/villes/6", @type: "Ville", nomVille: "Davidboeuf"}
1: {@id: "/api/villes/7", @type: "Ville", nomVille: "Benoitboeuf"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are trying to do something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
  {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```

This questions is also answered pretty nicely here:

[Iterate over object in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490713/iterate-over-object-in-angular)

[How to loop over object properties with ngFor in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45819123/how-to-loop-over-object-properties-with-ngfor-in-angular)

Comment: i tried this and it works : 
                        <option *ngFor="let ville of objectKeys(dropDownList) |
                            keys"
                            [value]="dropDownList[ville].idVille">
                            {{dropDownList[ville].nomVille}}
                        </option>

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using `*ngFor`, it only supports data is of type `array or iterables` only.

In your scenario data in your variable **dropDownList**  is either of type object or may be null | undefined. Hence this error occur. Console that data before using it.

Comment: it returns an object

Comment: That's the problem man !. It should return an array.