# How do I iterate a Http response object as Key Value pair?

Tags: angular

I have a below response from HTTP

```
getEmployee(id: number){
    this.empservice.getEmployee(id)
      .subscribe({
      next:(res)=>{
        this.obj = res;
      },
      error:(err)=>{
        alert("Error getting the employee");
        console.warn(err);
      }
    })
  }
```

I want to iterate the response in to a HTML Table or MAT table.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="obj">
        <tbody>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="(key, val) in obj[0]">
                <th>
                    {{ key }}
                </th>
                <td data-ng-repeat="row in obj">
                    {{ rowSource[key] }} 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Below is the response object that i get from API

```
{
    "employeeID": 999,
    "firstName": "Peter",
    "lastName": "Scotch",
    "phone": "8878767654",
    "email": "kumar@yahoo.com",
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you just wanting to know how to generically display properties of an object in an angular template?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop over object properties with ngFor in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45819123/how-to-loop-over-object-properties-with-ngfor-in-angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const testObj = {
    "employeeID": 999,
    "firstName": "Peter",
    "lastName": "Scotch",
    "phone": "8878767654",
    "email": "kumar@yahoo.com",
};

// 1 way
Object.entries(testObj).forEach(x => {

   let key = x[0]
   let value = x[1];
})

// 2 way 
Object.keys(testObj).forEach(key => {
  let value = testObj[key];
})
```

If you want to iterate it in html-table, try:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Key</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let key of Object.keys(obj)">
            <td>{{key}}</td>
            <td>{{obj[key]}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you. It gives an error Property 'Object' does not exist on type 'EmployeeComponent'. Sorry i am very new to Angular

Comment: replace your subscribe to `.subscribe({ next:(res)=>{ this.obj = Object.keys(res); }, error:(err)=>{ alert("Error getting the employee"); console.warn(err); } })`

Comment: I see one problem.. the order of the key is not maintained. is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a plain for (x in obj) { } loop:

```
    const user  = {
    "employeeID": 999,
    "firstName": "Peter",
    "lastName": "Scotch",
    "phone": "8878767654",
    "email": "kumar@yahoo.com",
}

for (let key in user) {
    if (user.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " : " + user[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks meher, i want to bind the output in html table and the order of the fields should be same. I think browser sorts the keys alphabetically

Comment: users = {
      "employeeID": 999,
      "firstName": "Peter",
      "lastName": "Scotch",
      "phone": "8878767654",
      "email": "kumar@yahoo.com",
  }
  
  myArr = [this.users];

Comment: <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>employee ID</th>
      <th>firstName</th>
      <th>lastName</th>
      <th>phone</th>
      <th>email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of myArr">
      <td>{{user.employeeID}}</td>
      <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
      <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
      <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
      <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    </tr>
   
  </tbody>
</table>