# my question is about Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'li' , Why am getting this error?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

**The error points to the *ngFor of nonvegfoodlist**

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
export class Menu 
{
  id : number;
  name :string;
}
const veg : Menu[] = [

  { id:1 , name:'Rice'},
  { id:2 , name:'Dosa'},
  { id:3 , name:'Biriyani'},
  {id :4 , name:'Pongal'}
];
const nonveg :Menu[] =[

  {id :5 , name:'Fish Curry'},
  {id:6, name:'Fish Fry'},
  { id:7 , name:'Half CB'}
];
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Restarunt';
  vegfoodlist = veg ;
  nonvegfoodlist = nonveg;

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<html>

  <body>
  <h1>
    {{title}}
  </h1>
  <h2>Veg Food list</h2>
  <div>
  <ul class="vegfoodlist">

    <li *ngFor ="let content of vegfoodlist">
     <span>{{content.name}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <ul class=" nonvegfoodlist">
    <li *ngFor ="Let conten in  nonvegfoodlist">
      <span>{{conten.name}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the list of errors that am getting from console:

> Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'li'
>
> Property binding ngFor not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make >sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations".

These are my questions,
1) is it possible to use multiple `ngFor`

Comment: Not a solution - but a suggestion - wouldn't it be better to have a single array of food items and have a property of "type" for each - which can be veg- or non-veg.. that way its easier to maintain and you can filter it to get all items with a type of "veg" etc to create the filtered arrays for your different lists. Then you could also extend it and have an "allergen" property as well eg: contains gluten....

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34012291 for more info (possible duplicate)

Answer (score 3):

`NgFor` is a structural directive which is located in the `CommonModule`. You need to import `CommonModule` and add into that module where you have used `NgFor`.

Answer (score 2):

there is a typo mistake in `*ngFor` replace `Let` with `let` and second mistake is you are using `Let conten in  nonvegfoodlist` while you can not use `in` in ngFor. so also need to replace `in` with `of` like this.

`let conten of  nonvegfoodlist`

```
<html>

  <body>
  <h1>
    {{title}}
  </h1>
  <h2>Veg Food list</h2>
  <div>
  <ul class="vegfoodlist">

    <li *ngFor ="let content of vegfoodlist">
     <span>{{content.name}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <ul class=" nonvegfoodlist">
    <li *ngFor ="let conten of  nonvegfoodlist">
      <span>{{conten.name}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

typo mistake, you need to use let instead of Let

```
<ul class=" nonvegfoodlist">
    <li *ngFor ="let conten of nonvegfoodlist">
      <span>{{conten.name}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <li *ngFor ="let conten in  nonvegfoodlist">
      <span>{{conten.name}}</span>
    </li>
```

I could see a typo here "Let" should be "let"

Answer (score 0):

Just a typo make it as

`<li *ngFor ="let content of vegfoodlist">
     <span>{{content.name}}</span>
 </li>`

and

`<li *ngFor ="let conten of  nonvegfoodlist">
      <span>{{conten.name}}</span>
 </li>`